# Calculation of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{2p+1}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$ for $|p|<1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Can someone help me with calculating this integral? I already found that it only converges for $|p|<1$, so I only need to calculate it for these p-values. I am thinking about using a contour integral, but couldn't work it out. I already calculated this integral for $p=0$ and found out that this gives $1/2$. Using numerical methods, I found that the result is $\frac{1}{2}\pi p \csc(\pi p)$, but I don't know the "proper" way to calculate this.

Comment: Use the classical keyhole contour.  Alternatively, use the Beta function and its relationship with the Gamma function.

Comment: By writing the integral as $\frac{1}{1-e^{2\pi ip}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^{2p+1}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$, you can use a semicircular contour.

Comment: @MarkViola When under the integral there is a function like $\log(x)$ or $x^{\alpha}$ times an even function (like here), it is often possible to use a semicircle contour, with a small semicircle around $0$. That way we get less residues than with the keyhole contour, so the computation is easier.

Comment: There are several ways to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real Analysis Methodolgy:

Let $x=\tan(\theta)$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2p+1}}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx&=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2p+1}(\theta)\cos^{-(2p-1)}(\theta)\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac12 B(p+1,1-p)\tag1\\\\
&=\frac12 \frac{\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(1-p)}{\Gamma(2)}\tag2\\\\
&=\frac12 p\Gamma(p)\Gamma(1-p)\tag3\\\\
&=\frac{p\pi \csc(\pi p)}2\tag4 
\end{align}$$

**NOTES**:

$(1)$ A definiton of the Beta function
$(2)$ Relationship between the Gamma function and the Beta function
$(3)$ Recurrence relationship of the Gamma function
$(4)$ Euler's reflection formula

---

Complex Analysis Methodolgy:

Here, we integrate $f(z)=\frac{z^{2p+1}}{(1+z^2)^2}$ along the classical keyhole contour $C$.  Proceeding, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C f(z)\,dz&=\int_\varepsilon^R \frac{x^{2p+1}}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx+\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(Re^{i\phi})^{2p+1}}{(1+(Re^{i\phi})^2)^2}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&+\int_R^\varepsilon \frac{x^{2p+1}e^{i2\pi (2p+1)}}{(1+x^2)^2}+\int_{2\pi}^0 \frac{(\varepsilon e^{i\phi})^{2p+1}}{(1+(\varepsilon e^{i\phi})^2)^2}\,i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi
\end{align}$$

Letting $R\infty$ and $\varepsilon\to 0^+$, we find that the right-hand side approaches $(1-e^{i4\pi p})\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2p+1}}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx$.

Applying the residue theorem, the contour integral must be equal to $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of the integrand at $x=\pm i$.

Equating and simplifying, we find again that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2p+1}}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx=\frac{p\pi \csc(\pi p)}{2}$$

Comment: If anyone wants to try this in detail, just be aware you need to use $i^p=e^{\pi ip/2},\,(-i)^p=e^{3\pi ip/2}$, because the contour's phase increases anticlockwise around the largest arc from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: @J.G. Happy Holidays!  Thank you for the comment.  Indeed, the keyhole is along the positive real axis, which corresponds to the branch cut of the complex logarithm.  And $z^c=e^{c\log(z)}$ where $0< \arg(z)\le 2\pi$.